# Select target application vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed the extension: ExtendScript Debugger
When I want to debug with it it says "Can't start a session without an active target and engine. Select an active target and engine before trying again."
I know that I need to select an target application but it doesn't appear in the toolbar at the bottom and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> doesn't work either.

I would love to know some way to select a target application.

Answer (score 4):

You need to "select the target application."

A couple ways to do this.

1. This will show up in the bottom right corner of VS Code [highlighted in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqJzD.png).  Click the yellow text and the installed adobe products on your computer will pull into the vscode editor, allowing you to choose which program to launch.
2. Add the target application to your launch.json file.

   ```
   {
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
       {
       "type": "extendscript-debug",
       "request": "launch",
       "dontBreakOnErrors": true,
       **"targetSpecifier": "indesign-14.064"**,
       "engineName": "whateverengine",
       "name": "A name",
       "program": "pathToTheScript",
       "stopOnEntry": false
       }
       ]
   }
   ```

More information here.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Adobe.extendscript-debug

Answer (score 3):

To hopefully save others the hours I've wasted on this, it appears ExtendScript Debugger does not work with either Big Sur &/or Apple Silicon. See the extension's [Q&A](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Adobe.extendscript-debug&ssr=false#review-details) and Reviews page & you'll see others with this problem.

For me, I did a full OS re-install (11.2.2), installed latest CC, then VSCode & ExtendScript Debugger. No "select the target application" option ever appears.

Answer (score 0):

For people on M1 Mac:
The option to select target will never appear. The solution is to download the Intel version of Visual Studio Code and use that instead. It's a little slow, but works.

https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/vscode-extendscript-debugger-on-m1-doesn-t-ask-to-select-target-and-selectactivetarget-not-found/td-p/12006537